# Log Periodic antenna Design

Tags: rf, pcb-design, radio, antenna

What are the specific formulas for designing a LP antenna? Values like boom length, spacing, number of segments needed, and segment width? desired range is 500 to 5000MHz. Thanks!

Comment: No formulas but two examples products: https://www.ettus.com/product/category/Antennas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are liable to find much information on this from eg amateur radio sites such as ARRL or RSGB, but also from many other websites. Stack Exchange does not permit me to tell you what tool may be suitable for finding this information by yourself.

Yee Ha !!! - [Log Periodeic design program](http://wb0dgf.com/LPCAD.htm) *Looks* superb.

Seems to be [formula based version of above page](http://glendash.com/Dash_of_EMC/Log_Periodic/Log_Periodic.htm)

[Links to 20 LP design articles](http://www.dxzone.com/catalog/Antennas/Log_Periodic/)

[Some excellent links wil; be available from here - hover over to get brief summaries](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=log+periodic+design&hl=en&safe=off&prmd=imvns&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=G2VpUM_8DczPmAWfzIGADg&sqi=2&ved=0CDgQsAQ&biw=2133&bih=1153)

You tube video - some value only but not really "design" [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PtKnpjWmj_8)

Comment: @kortuk - Yes. I know, I know. But surely ... .